# $ g (\cap_{i \in I} H_i )g^{-1} = \cap_{i \in I} g H_i g^{-1} $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a group, Let $I$ is indexing set.  $H_i$ be a subgroup of $G$. Prove that for any $g \in G$,

$$
g (\cap_{i \in I} H_i  )g^{-1} 
= \cap_{i \in I} g H_i g^{-1}
$$

---

some set notations

$$
\begin{aligned}
g \cap _{i \in I} H_i g^{-1}  &=\{ g hg^{-1} : h \in  \cap_{i \in I} H_i  \}
\\ gH_ig^{-1}                 &= \{ g hg^{-1}: h \in H_i   \} 
\end{aligned}
  $$

---

$\Leftarrow ]$ $( \cap_{i \in I} g H_i g^{-1}) \subseteq g( \cap_{i \in I H_i})g^{-1}$

Assume $x \in \cap_{i \in I } gH_ig^{-1}$

Now

$$\begin{aligned}
x \in gH_1g^{-1} \cap \dots  \cap gH_i g^{-1}
\\x \in gH_1g^{-1} \wedge \dots  \wedge x \in  gH_i g^{-1}
\end{aligned} $$

so  $$\begin{aligned}
x   &=g h_1 g^{-1}  && h_1 \in H_1
 \\ &= g h_2 g^{-1 } && h_2 \in H_2
 \\ &\vdots
 \\ &=g h_i g^{-1} && h_i \in H_i
\end{aligned} $$

**Missing argument, theorem, prop where means h is all H's**

Therefore  $$\begin{aligned}
    x &\in  \{ ghg^{-1}  : h\in \cap_{i \in I} h_i\}
\\ x &\in g (\cap_{i \in I} H_i)g^{-1}
\end{aligned} $$

$\Rightarrow]$  $  \left( g(\cap_{i \in I}   H_i)g^{-1}  \subseteq g H_i g^{-1}     )    \right )$

$x\in g (\cap_{i \in I} H_i)g^{-1}$

making of the form

$$ x = ghg^{-1}  \text{     where } h \in \cap_{i \in I} H_i$$

Now, $$\begin{aligned}
 x &= ghg^{-1}  \text{     where } h \in H_1
  \\ &\vdots 
  \\ x &= ghg^{-1}  \text{     where } h \in H_i
\end{aligned} $$

so $$\begin{aligned}
x &\in  gH_1g^{-1}  
\\ &\vdots 
\\ x &\in gH_ig^{-1}  
\end{aligned} $$

that is $$\begin{aligned}
x  &\in gH_1 g^{-1 } \wedge \dots  \wedge x \in gH_i g^{-1 }
\\x &\in gH_1 g^{-1 } \cap \dots \cap gH_i g^{-1 }
\\ x &\in \cap_{i \in I} gH_i g^{-1}
\end{aligned} $$

*case for when the $H_i$ are normal*

*Proposition 13 sec 4.4 Automorphism Dummit's*

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of group $G$. Then $G$ acts by conjugation on $H$ as automorphism of $G$

call $$H = \cap_{i \in I} H_i $$

$$\begin{aligned}
   x &\in g ( \cap _{i \in I}) g^{-1}
\\ x &\in g (H_1 \cap H_2 \cap \dots  \cap H_i)g^{-1}
\\ x &\in g Hg^{-1}
\end{aligned} $$

From the proposition, This conjugation is an automorphism so  $x \in g H_i g^{-1} \Leftrightarrow x \in H_i$. Now $x\in H \Leftrightarrow x \in gHg^{-1}$

so $x\in H$ means that

$$\begin{aligned}
x &\in H_1 \cap \dots \cap H_i
\\ x &\in H_1 \wedge  \dots  \wedge x \in H_i
\end{aligned}
 $$

again automorphism means that $\forall g\in G$

$$\begin{aligned}
x &\in g H_1 g^{-1} \wedge \dots \wedge x\in g H_ig^{-1}
\\ x&\in   g H_1 g^{-1} \cap  \dots \cap  g H_ig^{-1}
\\ x&\in \cap_{i \in I} gHg^{-1}
\end{aligned} $$

\textbf{Case when the H's are not normal}

Comment: I'm not following. Is there a question somewhere in there?

Comment: Missing something in part  $\Leftarrow ]$ $( \cap_{i \in I} g H_i g^{-1}) \subseteq g( \cap_{i \in I H_i})g^{-1}$. Its right the  beginning and bold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unless i have missed something you may be over-thinking this one. something like the following sequence of equivalences should be all that is required

$$ \begin{align}
x \in g(\cap_i H_i)g^{-1} &\iff g^{-1}xg \in \cap_i H_i \\&\iff \forall i.g^{-1}xg \in H_i \\&\iff \forall i.x \in gH_ig^{-1} \\&\iff x \in \cap_i gH_ig^{-1}
\end{align}
$$